# Casting to base and backwards using (no) pointers

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

I'm a bit confused about base class copy constructors.

Let's sat I have this code:

```
struct object
{
    object() {}
    object(const object& value)
    void function() { }

    template <class any> operator any() const
    {
        return any(*this);
    }
};

template <class any> struct primitive
{
    any& _value;
    primitive(any& value) : _value(value) {}
    primitive(const object& value);
    operator any() const;

};
```

Is it possible to use these classes like this?

Casting a int to a object:

```
(object)primitive<int>(x);
```

Copying the object by calling the copy constructor:

```
object y = (object)primitive<int>(x);
```

and still being able to convert the object back to an int:

```
int z = (int)(primitive<int>)y;
```

And how could this be achieved? I don't ask for complete code, just for right directions.

Or would a better approach be a wrapper called object, around a base pointer for the derived class?

Hope someone could give me some information!

Comment: Where do you suspect you have a base and derived class? I don't see any inheritance going on. Maybe it would be worth describing what you try to achieve rather than asking about a specific technique which has lots of gaps in it?

Comment: @Dietmar Kühl Thank you for your reaction. I'm trying to create a sort of Java `Object` class. Where functions could be called on like `string toString();` etc.

Comment: @Tim did you have a look at POCO "DynamicAny" ? It may do what you want already.

Comment: Is something like a `boost::any` with a few supported functions what you are looking for so? Essentially, allowing type erasure while still maintaining some type specific functionality? BTW, you should **stopp** using Java-style (or C-style) casting in C++! It is non-descriptive of what it supposed to do and hard to search for. Use the proper casting operator (e.g. `static_cast<T>()` in the cases you seem to have) instead - or, better, yet, not casting at all!

Comment: Thanks, the approach of `boost::any` will do what I want.